# installed numpy but can't import

Tags: python, numpy, module, pip, importerror

I have already looked at other questions, but they either haven't been the same situation or haven't worked.

I am using windows 10.  I had python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.7.2 (weren't on path) so I downloaded 3.8 and added to path during download.

on cmd did "pip install numpy"

```
C:\Users\Aidan>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/40/c6eae19892551ff91bdb15f884fef2d42d6f58da55ab18fa540851b48a32/numpy-1.17.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (12.7MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 12.7MB 3.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.17.4

C:\Users\Aidan>python.exe -m pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\aidan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.17.4)
```

When I go to python 3.8 this happens:

```
>>>import NumPy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import NumPy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NumPy'
```

and the same happens in 3.7 and 3.6.

I have tried pip uninstall and pip install again.

```
C:\Users\Aidan>pip uninstall numpy
Uninstalling numpy-1.17.4:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\aidan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.17.4.dist-info\*
    c:\users\aidan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\*
    c:\users\aidan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\scripts\f2py.exe
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.17.4

C:\Users\Aidan>pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/40/c6eae19892551ff91bdb15f884fef2d42d6f58da55ab18fa540851b48a32/numpy-1.17.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.17.4
```

From my research I know that having multiple pythons can be sometimes be a problem, but it never says why or which ones I need to get rid of to make it work.  Below I will provide any extra info that may help.

```
C:\Users\Aidan>pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.17.4
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\aidan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:


C:\Users\Aidan>python --version
Python 3.7.0
```

In python 3.8:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
        print (p)



C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\idlelib
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.zip
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\DLLs
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages
```

In python 3.7:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
        print (p)



C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\idlelib
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
```

This was the first time I've ever done anything with path or downloading modules so sorry for being a noob at this stuff.

Comment: `import NumPy` won't work because it's case-sensitive. Should be `import numpy`

Comment: i genuenly am an idiot, how could i not see that. thanks. but that only worked for 3.7 64bit, do you know how i can make it work on 3.8?

Comment: At the start you say you downloaded 3.8 and added it to the path, but your first block of output shows you having `pip install`ed to the `\python37` environment, not 3.8. You need to double-check that you've actually installed it in your 3.8 environment.

Comment: How about using virtual environements for different python versions. with `conda` it is very simple

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the latest (1.19.4) NumPy version: try installing

`pip install numpy==1.19.3`